# How to apply an environment variable for the whole command

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, environment-variables, urxvt

In my Bash terminal, I regularly execute a chain of commands. For example:

```
cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3
```

Now, I want to define an environment variable which is applied to all three commands and which only scoped to those commands. I tried:

```
MY_VAR=abc cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3
```

But it seems that now only `cmd1` sees `MY_VAR`.

Is there a way to apply the environment variable to all three commands? I know I could `export` in advance, but I prefer to declare the environment variable locally in an ad-hoc fashion, so it will never impact subsequent commands.

It it matters, I am using `urxvt` as terminal emulator.

Comment: According to the SHELL GRAMMAR section of the [bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), this type of variable assignment is part of a "simple command", and hence cannot be applied to compound commands (like "lists" of commands separated by `&&` or `;`).

Comment: `(export MY_VAR=abc; cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repeat it: `MY_VAR=abc cmd1 && MY_VAR=abc cmd2 && MY_VAR=abc cmd3`

Or use a subshell:

```
   # wrapper subshell for the commands
   cmds () 
   {
      cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3
   }

   # invoke it
   MY_VAR=abc cmds
```

If you need to enter the whole thing in one go, do:

```
   cmds() { cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3; }; MY_VAR=abc cmds
```

Comment: Notice the line breaks in the subshell definition? If you need to enter it in one go you can condense the subshell like this: `cmds () { cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3; }; MY_VAR=abc cmds`

Comment: Appreciated, this is what I needed!

Comment: This is more complicated than it looks. The function does not run in a subshell (I tested in bash, zsh, dash, and ksh). The variable is temporarily set in the shell during the function in all tested shells, but is only exported to commands run in the function in bash and zsh. As a result, this does not work in dash or ksh. (There's a bash tag in the question, but for anyone else reading this...)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
export MY_VAR="abc"
cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3
unset MY_VAR          # only nessesary if you want to remove the variable again
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid using `export` as this is easily forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is:

`MY_VAR=abc; cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3`

What makes the difference is the colon after the assignment.

Without the colon `;`, `MY_VAR=abc cmd1 && ...` this cause the assignment to be part of the `cmd1 element` of the conditional expression. Anything at the other side of the 
logical AND: `&&` can not see the local environment of the other condition elements.

Comment: That would require `MY_VAR` to be exported.

Comment: @EdMorton, really. I tried it before to make sure. An export is needed for the variable to propagate within the scope of other processes/shells. There the colon `;` only separate blocks of commands but everything is already in the scope of current shell. So no need to export.

Comment: Put `echo "$MY_VAR"` in `tst.sh` then run `MY_VAR=abc ./tst.sh` and it'll output `abc` while `MY_VAR=abc; ./tst.sh` will output a null string.

Comment: @EdMorton this because `./tst.sh` is spawning another shell process. Now I get it ^^

Comment: id suggest `MY_VAR=abc && cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3` instead. && ensures that execution environment for those 4 commands is the same

Comment: I think that the author of this post has misintended`&&` for `;`. `&&` allows commands to share working environment but `;` doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple script to echo my variable to try and simulate a command.
Also declared 1 "global environment variable" with the `export` command.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $ABC
```

### Input

```
$ export ABC=globalEnvironmentVariable
$ (ABC=localGroupVariable; ./test.sh && ./test.sh) && ABC=commandVariable ./test.sh && ./test.sh
```

### Output

```
localGroupVariable
localGroupVariable
commandVariable
globalEnvironmentVariable
```